# Flurry custom events

Tags: events, implementation, flurry

I have this popup in my app where I ask a question with "yes" or "no" being the possible options a user can choose. I would like to track a funnel of users that see the popup and then tap either yes or no. I would like to take it one step further though I would like to a/b test the text in the popup so I would like to see what users saw the popup with text A and tapped yes or no as well as who say text B etc etc.

I'm trying to figure out what custom events need to be where. Currently I have a custom event called popup and I pass in either a yes or no to the event. The issue is when I go to make a funnel I can only see the parent event called popup I can't select yes or no for the funnel. So do I need to create an event for the popup, for the text the user saw, for yes button and no button all individually for it to work? Seems like it would be a lot of events to have to create. Or is it possible to have a parent event called popup and in there have custom events for the different texts as well as what button they selected?

Comment: Also to make it a little more confusing I have 2 popup with yes and no answers. Would I be able to reuse the Yes and No events or would I need to do something like popup1_yes and popup2_yes?

Comment: So I talked to flurry about this and they said you can only setup funnels on events not params.